# Why do I get Error: Could not find or load main class .jar when I run docker image

Tags: java, spring, docker, jar

I have written my docker file as below:

```
  From java:8
  EXPOSE 8081
  ADD /target/Demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Demo.jar
  ENTRYPOINT ["java",".jar","Demo.jar"]
```

("Demo" is my project name. It creates a Spring boot application.)

I am using a Linux machine.

Comment: What about this `ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /Demo.jar" ]`?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have mentioned **"-jar"** in the ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","Demo.jar"]. you can try to execute the jar using normal java command( **`java -jar target/Demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`** ) to make sure the jar builds properly.

```
FROM java:8
ADD target/Demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Demo.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","Demo.jar"]
```

Answer (score 6):

You might have a typo:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","Demo.jar"]
```